# Query for A Likes B, B Likes C, Two Degrees of Separation

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

suppose you have the following table named Likes:

```
A|B
---
a|b
a|f
a|e
a|i
b|a
b|i
c|d
e|p
```

In this table, values in A represent people who "like" people in B. So, a likes b, a likes f, a likes e, and so forth. **How do you write a query such that you get the number of different users who are two degrees of separation from each user**? So as an example, if a likes b, then b is one degree of separation from a. If a likes b, and b likes c, then c is two degrees of separation from a. One more example, if a likes b, and b likes a, then a is two degrees of separation from itself (we don't exclude cycles). So the output should be something like this:

```
User|CountOfUsersWhoAreTwoDegreesFromUser
-----------------------------------------
 a  |  -
 b  |  -
 c  |  -
 e  |  -
```

Now, I'm not sure what our counts would be for each user, so I didn't write it in the above table. Also, no persons in the table Likes like themselves. So you will not see a combination like a|a in Likes, or b|b in Likes. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: A does not have unique values...

Comment: Note that as you have phrased the problem, if (A, B) and (B, A) then A will be counted as being two degrees from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need consider only two connections at once, this can be done with joins. (If you had to consider the full closure of the Likes relation, then you would need the full power of recursion, such as an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm.)

```
SELECT X.A AS user, COUNT(DISTINCT Y.B) AS countOfUsersWhoAreTwoDegreesFromUser
FROM Likes AS X
    INNER JOIN Likes AS Y
    ON X.B = Y.A
GROUP BY user
```

EDIT: To be clear, this problem is simple and reasonable efficient for any *fixed* degree of separation.y

EDIT 2: Here's a variant solution which will prevent a user from being counted as two degrees from themselves. This varies from the literal problem description, but might be what was intended.

```
SELECT X.A AS user, COUNT(DISTINCT Y.B) AS countOfUsersWhoAreTwoDegreesFromUser
FROM Likes AS X
    INNER JOIN Likes AS Y
    ON X.B = Y.A
WHERE X.A <> Y.B
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: The answer as originally posted will handle that case as specified in the original question, counting A as two degrees from itself. If this is not what was actually intended, then the second query will handle that case in the more intuitively obvious way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select primary.A, count(*)
from likes primary
   inner join likes secondary on primary.B = secondary.A
group by primary.A
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: this approach is not Scalable ...
If you are interested ONLY and ONLY in two degrees, we can go for a self join ...

Condition T1.A <> T2.B is to filter out A liking A, Distinct is applied so that even if A like C by two degrees by two different path, its still counted as 1.

```
SELECT T.A, Count(T.B)
FROM
(
  SELECT  DISTINCT T1.A, T2.B 
    FROM Table1 T1
   INNER JOIN Table1 T2 on T1.B = T2.A AND T1.A <> T2.B
) T
GROUP BY T.A
```

Answer (score 0):

To cope with an arbitrary value for degree, a CTE could be used in PostgreSQL:

```
with recursive graph (a, b, path, degree) as
(
  select a, b, array[a::text, b::text] as path, 1 as degree
  from likes

  union all

  select l.a, l.b, g.path || l.b::text, g.degree + 1
  from likes l
    join graph g on l.a = g.b and l.b  g.a
)
select *
from graph
where degree = 2
```